# Extracting child node value from XML using T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I'm stuck on trying to get the 'availability' node's value out of an envelope returned via T-SQL from a Microsoft Lync database. The usual methods of .value('(/MyElement/Something)[1]') doesn't seem to work for me.

```
<state xsi:type="aggregateState" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/09/sip/state">
<availability>3500
</availability>
<delimiter xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/09/sip/commontypes" />
<timeZoneBias>-60
</timeZoneBias>
<timeZoneName>GMT Daylight Time
</timeZoneName>
<timeZoneAbbreviation>GMT Daylight Time
</timeZoneAbbreviation>
<device>computer
</device>
<end xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/09/sip/commontypes" />
</state>
```

This is the query I've been experimenting with:

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    CAST(SUBSTRING(i.Data, 0, 4000) as XML).value('(/state//availability)[1]', 'varchar(256)')
FROM dbo.PublishedCategoryInstanceView AS i
INNER JOIN dbo.CategoryDef AS d
    ON (d.CategoryId = i.CategoryId)
WHERE i.PublisherId = (SELECT ResourceId FROM dbo.Resource
                        WHERE UserAtHost = 'my.email@mydomain.local')
ORDER BY i.LastPubTime DESC
```

All I get back is 'NULL' unless I do `CAST(SUBSTRING(i.Data, 0, 4000) as XML).value('(/)[1]', 'varchar(256)')` which returns `3500-60GMT Daylight TimeGMT Daylight Timecomputer`

I do know that when I strip out the three attributes on the state element I can perform normal XML queries against the data so I can get around this by manipulating the string with a few replace statements but I'd rather learn exactly what I'm doing wrong here, if anyone can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're just plain **ignoring** the XML namespace that exists on your XML root node:

```
<state xsi:type="aggregateState" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/09/sip/state">
       ******************************************************
```

You need to include that in your T-SQL query!

Try something like this:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/09/sip/state')
SELECT TOP 1 
    CAST(SUBSTRING(i.Data, 0, 4000) as XML).value('(/state//availability)[1]', 'varchar(256)')
FROM 
    dbo.PublishedCategoryInstanceView AS i
```